# How can I get CPU time, memory time and CPU usage per query in Datastax Cassandra?

Tags: python, cassandra, nosql, datastax

I'm using datastax cassandra in my graduate work and I want to get this metric but I can't find any documentation about it. I am using python connector. Is it possible to get this information about each query executed? If yes, how can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using a paid subscription based [**DataStax Enterprise / DSE**](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise) Cassandra cluster, you could leverage [**DSE OpsCenter**](https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/docs/6.8/online-help/metrics-reference.html) to monitor various metrics of the cluster.

[DataStax Python Driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/latest/api/cassandra/metrics/) also has metrics reporting capability that you could check.

If this is something else, please update your question and someone would be able to jump in answer to that question.